# Making something like Fragment in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I writing app for UWP.

I have app very similar to Windows 10 Mail app.

I have this UI

[image]

Here is xaml of this screen

```
<Grid BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/Background.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" BorderBrush="#FFF5F1F1" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <Button x:Name="MenuButton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Menu-100.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="logoutbutton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,650,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="43" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Logout_Button.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="63,2,-121,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1338" BorderBrush="#FFFDFDFD" Padding="0,0,0,1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="В Работе" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="1218" FontSize="32" FontFamily="SF UI Display" Padding="550,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" Margin="63,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
        <GridView   x:Name="OrdersGridView" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>



</Grid>
```

I make Binding in code like this:

```
public async void Down()
    {

       
       

        RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
        //Get all products
        var orders = await wc.GetOrders(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "per_page", "100" }, { "status","processing"} }); // Dodelat filtr dlaya teh chto v  rabote




        string products = orders.ToFormattedJsonString();

       

        List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);
        



       foreach (RootObject root in rootObjectData)
        {

            
            string date = root.date_created;
            string name = root.billing.first_name;
            
           

            Orders = new ObservableCollection<RootObject>(rootObjectData) { new RootObject { date_created = date}

    
    };
        OrdersGridView.ItemsSource = Orders;



        };
    }
}
```

}

I need to open smth like `Fragment`.

Here is UI how it need to be like:

[image]

How I can do this?

Thank's for help so much!

Comment: Do you mean Android Fragment? I guess you should create a custom control for Order details and set it's DataContext each time user selects another order.

Comment: I need to open for example new gridview or smth like this in right side with data. Maybe you know resources with tutorials? @foxanna

Comment: I would create a custom control similar to this example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Creating-Custom-Controls-a031a7ea I would put such control into xaml and change it's DataContext to selected order when OrdersGridView selected item changes. This control should also change it's visibility depending on whether it's DataContext is set.