# UWP App Template

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, user-controls, uwp

I'm developing a UWP application. The design of the UI is similar to the Email app in Windows 10 ([My app design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsvyD.png)).

This is my XAML code:

```
<Page
x:Class="Milano.InWork"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Milano"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/Background.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="720" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" BorderBrush="#FFF5F1F1" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0">
        <Button x:Name="MenuButton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="38" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Menu-100.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="logoutbutton" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,650,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="43" Width="38">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="Images/Logout_Button.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="47" Margin="63,2,-121,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1338" BorderBrush="#FFFDFDFD" Padding="0,0,0,1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="В Работе" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="1218" FontSize="32" FontFamily="SF UI Display" Padding="550,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="668" Margin="63,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
        <GridView   x:Name="OrdersGridView" >
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <Grid Height="204" BorderBrush="#FFFBF8F8" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding date_created}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350" Height="50" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  TextAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,146,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.address_1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" />
                            <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,86,-1,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding billing.first_name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="60" Width="350" FontFamily="SF UI Display" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Light" Foreground="White" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </ScrollViewer>



</Grid>
```

What I need to do: When user clicks on `Grid` in right place of screen app show something like Fragment (I know this is Android thing) with some fields and data, like in the Email Windows 10 app:

- [Before clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUq0j.jpg)
- [After clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4xMI.png)

How I can implement this? 
Or where I can read tutorial or something like this?

Thank's for help!

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791550/making-something-like-fragment-in-uwp) question. Just a different OP asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a typical Master/Detail design in UWP, you can refer to the official [Master/detail sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail), when on wide-screen mode, it uses [ContentPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to show the details, and when on narrow-screen mode, it navigates with parameter to the detail page. The official sample is so clear, you can have a check.

From your first image, I think you can use a `ListView` to replace your `GridView`, for both controls, you can use [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx) or [ItemClick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick.aspx) event to show the details, if you want to use `ItemClick` event, please don't forget to enable the [IsItemClickEnabled property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.itemclick.aspx).

There is a [MasterDetails (Mail App) sample](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/MasterDetail) which uses [Template 10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) as project template, if you're interest in this sample, you can also have a check.